# Wordpress add exiting page as custom post type archive page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a page with a ready custom template, Ex: example.com/research/labs/

I also have customs posts types with the slug of 'labs', Ex: example.com/labs/post-name1.

My objective is to make the existing page an archive page for labs posts, basically making example.com/labs/ to example.com/research/labs/

I have tried changing the custom post slug to "research/labs" instead of just "labs" using a rewrite on the custom post created.

```
register_post_type( 'labs',
  array(
    'labels' => array(
      'name' => __( 'labs','lstheme' ),
      'singular_name' => __( 'labs' )
    ),
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
     'rewrite' => array( 
    'slug' => 'research/labs', 
    'with_front' => FALSE 
     ),
     'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments','author' ),
  )
```

Changing the slug makes the WordPress posts Archive page URL as I want it to (example.com/research/labs/), but the page that was working before the change becomes a blank page.

Probably a very beginner question, but I couldn't find a solution for that…

Comment: After changing the `slug` argument, did you 'flush the rewrite rules'? You could do that by navigating to `the admin panel of your website > Settings > Permalinks > Click Save Changes at the bottom of the page`. That would flush the rewrite rules and then it should work again.

Comment: Yes, I did. No change, though.